# Nested foreach loop in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to draw some vector fields on a triangle, and I am using nested `\foreach` loop to do that, however in the inner loop, you can't use the outer loop variable as the numeric range. For e.g. The following code does not work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
{\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(-1,1) -- cycle;}
\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,1}
  \foreach \y in {0,0.1,...,1-\x}
  {
  \draw [->] (\x,\y)--(-1 + \x + 2*\y,-\y);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to do nested loop like this? Or I have to manually go through the loop for each `\y` which is `\x` dependent?

Comment: Could you point out more clearly what doesn't work for you, because, as for me, your code snippet at least gets compiled. There's some issues with loop-variables, but it works.

Comment: The nested loops work fine for me. Except when `\x` is `0` the inner loop is `{0,0.1,...,0}` and then processes the `0.1` as well. Your drawing code seems just not right. You might also want to use integers instead, i.e. `{0,1,...,10}` and then use `\x/10` to avoid rounding issues with the loop variables.

Comment: I copied the wrong codes above, what didn't compile was if the inner loop range is an operation of `\x`, for e.g., `1-\x`, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that vector should come out from inside of triangle (in your post it is not true). I think you stuck because of imprecise float arithmetic, so you'd better switch to integers:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(-1,1) -- cycle;

    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 10}
        \foreach \y in {0, ..., \x} {
            \draw[->] (1 - 0.1*\x,0.1*\y) -- (-0.1*\x + 0.2*\y,-0.1*\y);
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MathChief: Note that I've updated my solution according to your fixes.

Comment: Updated solution, using Andrew's hint about default step.

Answer (score 10):

I find that `\foreach` can be a little fussy over what it accepts as endpoints of a range.  Whilst I don't know the details of what does and doesn't work, I do know how to get your example (with the `1-\x`) to work: do the computation before the `\foreach` and save the result in a new macro.  Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16411/86
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(-1,1) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {0,.1,...,1}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{1-\x}
  \foreach \y in {0,.1,...,\z}
  {
  \draw [->] (\x,\y)--(-1 + \x + 2*\y,-\y);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Note that I haven't corrected the other issues: even when `\x` is 1 then the loop is executed for `\y` being 0.1.  Using integers gets round this as then the range can be specified as `0,...,\z` since the default step-size is 1.)